# How to get the center part of string on C#

Tags: c#, .net

i need the center string of Rocky44 only using C#

```
Hi <a href="http://example.com/index.php?action=profile"><span>Rocky44</span></a>
```

I tried the some split method but can't work

```
string[] result = temp.Split(new string[] { "<a href=" + "http://example.com/index.php?action=profile" + "><span>" , "</span></a>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

**Example:**

```
Hi <a href="http://example.com/index.php?action=profile"><span>Rocky44</span></a>
```

**To:**

```
Rocky44
```

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: He already showed what he tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track; you're just not escaping your quotes correctly:

```
string[] result = temp.Split(new string[] { "<a href=\"http://example.com/index.php?action=profile\"><span>" , "</span></a>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Of course, this is assuming that your input will always be in exactly the given format. As I4V mentions, an HTML parser may come in handy if you're trying to do anything more complicated.

Comment: @user2430116: I'm glad. Please accept an answer so that people know your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 9):

Use an html parser. I will give an example using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)

```
string html = @"Hi <a href=""http://example.com/index.php?action=profile""><span>Rocky44</span></a>";
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var text = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span").InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the index of `<span>` and `</span>` using the [`IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) method.

Then (adjusting for the length of `<span>`) use the [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx) method to get the desired text.

```
string FindLinkText(string linkHtml)
{
    int startIndex = linkHtml.IndexOf("<span>") + "<span>".Length,
        length = linkHtml.IndexOf("</span>") - startIndex;

    return linkHtml.Substring(startIndex, length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only going to get this sort of thing (eg **this** sort of HTML) then I would use regex. Else, **DO NOT USE IT**.

```
string HTML = @"Hi <a href="http://example.com/index.php?action=profile"><span>Rocky44</span></a>"
var result = Regex.Match(HTML, @".*<a.*><span.*>(.*)</span></a>").Groups[1].Value;
```